# Add Document in Word Using Macro (in Ribbon)

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon, word-2007

I have a custom Ribbon in MS Word 2007 that I have a number of macros in.

The existing macros do things like:

- Sort formatting
- Find & replace text
- Add header & footer

I'd like to have another macro that will add a document, within my document. These are basically information leaflets that will be added to a letter as required. I don't want the user to have to open the existing leaflet documents, just select the appropriate one from the Ribbon to add it as a new section in their open document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the **Alt + I, L** command.

If you had 2003 or earlier, you could have looked at the Insert menu (**Alt + I**) to learn that File is (**L**). Pity you have to use a ribbon.

The recorder is **Alt + T**(ools), **M**(acros), **R**(ecord) and same keystrokes to stop.

Comment: That's excellent thanks Serenity.

It's a shame people chose to downvote my first question that although looks simple, is something I've not done before.